# Embed twitter timeline with tweets sorted chronologically descending

Tags: html, twitter

so I tried to embed a twitter page url in my web application [this link](https://publish.twitter.com/) and it looks good but the problem is that I see the not the most recent tweet but the most commented tweet.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-tweet-limit="20" data-dnt="true" data-theme="light" data-chrome="nofooter noborders" data-height="auto" href="https://my-twitter-page-url">Tweets</a>
```

Any idea how can I fix the issue ?

Comment: The widget you are using there does not appear to offer any option for this, so: You _can't_.

Comment: Are there any other widgets that display the twitter timeline and offer support for that ?

Comment: Dunno; but that kind of question would be off-topic here to begin with.